# route all traffic over gre tunnel

Tags: lxc, tunnel, openvswitch

I have an openvswitch sw1 with subnet 10.207.39.0/24 that has lxc containers attached and I have the same on another physical server and I have successfully connected these using a GRE tunnel.  However, the lxc containers have additional ports on additional openvswitches, e.g. sw4 with subnet 192.220.39.0/24 and I want to push that traffic over the single gre tunnel on sw1 because there is only one physical interface and it's not possible to have multiple gre tunnels on each openvswitch with the same physical interface IP addr endpoints.  Is it possible to push the traffic on the other openvswitches over the gre tunnel on sw1?  Or is there a better way to connect multiple subnets in lxc containers on two physical hosts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this "myself" - with help from two links provided below -  (after sleeping on it and relentless google searches over several frustrating days).

I realize the solution is pretty simple and would be clear to a networking professional. I am an Oracle DBA and only know as much networking as I need to work with orabuntu-lxc software, LXC containers, and Oracle software, so please keep that in mind if the below is "obvious" - it wasn't obvious to me in my network ignorance.

I got the clue on how to solve the actual steps from this blog post:

http://www.cnblogs.com/popsuper1982/p/3800548.html

I confirmed that any subnet should be routable over a GRE tunnel from this blog post (which gave me hope to keep working towards a solution):

https://supportforums.adtran.com/thread/1408

In particular the author stated in the adtran comment that "GRE tunnels have no limitation on the types of traffic which can traverse it. It can route multiple subnets without multiple tunnels."

That post told me that the solution was likely a routing solution and that only one GRE tunnel would be needed for this use case.

Note that this feature of "no limitation" on the types of traffic is great for Oracle RAC because we need to be able to send multicast over the GRE tunnel for RAC.

This use case:

I am building an Oracle RAC infrastructure to run in LXC Linux containers.  I have a public network 10.207.39.0/24 on openvswitch sw1 and a private RAC interconnect network 192.220.39.0/24 on openvswitch sw4. I want to be able to build the RAC in LXC linux containers that span multiple physical hosts and so I created a GRE tunnel to connect the 10.207.39.1 tunnel endpoint on colossus to 10.207.39.5 tunnel endpoint on guardian.

Here is the setup details:

Host "guardian":

LAN wireless physical network interface:  wlp4s0  (IP 192.168.1.11)

sw1  10.207.39.5

sw4 192.220.39.5

Host "colossus":

LAN wireless physical network interface:  wlp4s0  (IP 192.168.1.15)

sw1  10.207.39.1

sw4 192.220.39.1

Step 1:

Create GRE tunnel between sw1 openvswitches on both physical hosts with physical wireless LAN network interface end points:

Host "guardian":  Create gre tunnel phys hosts (guardian --> colossus).

sudo ovs-vsctl add-port sw1 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=gre options:remote_ip=192.168.1.15

Host "colossus":  Create gre tunnel phys hosts (colossus --> guardian).

sudo ovs-vsctl add-port sw1 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=gre options:remote_ip=192.168.1.11

Step 2:

Route the 192.220.39.0/24 network over the established GRE tunnel as shown below:

Host "guardian": route 192.220.39.0/24 openvswitch sw4 over GRE tunnel:

sudo route add -net 192.220.39.0/24 gw 10.207.39.5 dev sw1

Host "colossus": route 192.220.39.0/24 openvswitch sw4 over GRE tunnel:

sudo route add -net 192.220.39.0/24 gw 10.207.39.1 dev sw1

Note:  To add additional subnets repeat step 2 for each subnet.

Note on MTU:

Also, you have to allow for GRE encapsulation in MTU if you want to ssh over these tunnels.

Therefore in the above example for the main GRE tunnel connecting the hosts, we need MTU to be set to 1420 to allow 80 for the GRE header.

MTU on the LXC container virtual interfaces on the sw1 switches need to be set to MTU=1420 in the LXC container config files.

MTU on the LXC container virtual interfaces on the sw4 switches need to be set to MTU=1420 in the LXC container config files.

Note that the MTU on the openvswitches sw1 and sw4 should automatically set to the MTU on the LXC intefaces as long as ALL LXC virtual interfaces are set to the new lower MTU values, so explicitly setting MTU on the openvswitches sw1 and sw4 themselves should not be necessary.

If run into issues still with SSH over the tunnels, but ping works cross-hosts cross-containers, then re-check all MTU settings on the virtual interfaces and openvswitches and recheck.